# Netbeans Editor, how can I supress warnings?

Tags: java, netbeans, editor

In eclipse, I can say to editor (and of course compiler) I don't use that variable so remove the underline with
@SuppressWarnings("unused")

Anyone knows in Netbeans 6.9 how can I remove the underline of unused variables in editor?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you have variables declared and never used ,why dont u remove it from the code.

Comment: Because I'm using Tapestry, in tapestry you have a class and its Template, sometimes you dont use the variables in the code but yes in the template (tml), so it appears un used in the editor. With Eclipse you can remove it with @SupressWarnings("unused"). 

For example you have this variable:
@Property private String name;
...
But you don't use the variable in your .java file, but the variable is used in your tml file
<body>
${name}
</body>

So, the variable is marked as unused by the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` by hand?

A bit of extra research tells me that `javac -X` includes a set of warnings that can be turned on/off using -Xlint.  Unfortunately, "unused" is not on the list.  So if (and that's a "big if") the netbeans compiler is based on javac, you might be out of luck.

Comment: Yes, I had tried with @SupressWarnings("unused") by hand and it only works in eclipse.
Thank you for the response but I'm not talking about the compiler, I'm talking about the Netbeans editor. Regards

Comment: @iberck - unless there is something very strange about Netbeans, the Netbeans java editor uses an embedded incremental java compiler to implement syntax highlighting, underlining of unused variables, etc.  I am talking about **that** compiler.